# Regex para tokens de números positivos, negativos, soma e subtração

Tags: python, regex

Tenho que fazer uma analisador léxico em python usando o [PLY](https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/).
Usa-se REGEX para pegar os tokens:

Exemplo:

```
t_FLUTUANTE = r'flutuante'
```

A expressão acima dá um *match* com a palavra `flutuante` e me retorna um token (*como o ply retorna o tokens por hora não será necessario explicar como funciona*).

**O Problema:**
A minha dificuldade é na hora de pegar os tokens de números negativos, positivos soma e subtração.

A minha entrada teste é:

```
a := -1
y := +2
b := 2
c := 3+4
z := 20 + 42
funcao(-1)
funcao( -1)
funcao(a, -1)
```

Se meu regex é:

```
[+-]?\d+
```

Os *matches* serão:

[image: Primeira tentativa de expressão regular!]

Mas perceba que na variável `c`, ficou `+4`, e isso não pode acontecer pois na real era pra ser uma soma.

Pois bem se eu modificar um pouco consigo um resultado melhor.

```
((\D)[+-]\d+)|\d+
```

Sua saída é:

[image: Tentativa Numero 2!]

De fato um resultado melhor. Mas existem alguns espaços entre as funções e a variável `a`, inclusive o regex pegou em uma das funções o *match* `(-1`.

Como fazer para pegar certo?

Estou usando o site https://www.regextester.com/ para testar as minhas expressões, estou desativando o multiline (`m`) no site pois no Ply não consegui ativar ele.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html#negated) `\D` corresponde a um caractere (qualquer um que não seja `\d`) e portanto esse caractere também fará parte do *match*. Por isso ele pega o caractere que está antes do `-` (no caso, o espaço ou o `(`).

Uma alternativa para que isso não ocorra é usar [*lookbehind*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
((?<=\D)[+-]\d+)|\d+
```

A sintaxe `(?<=` define um *lookbehind*, que serve para verificar se algo existe antes da posição atual. A diferença é que o *lookbehind* só olha se tem algo, mas o seu conteúdo não faz parte do *match* (isso é chamado de [*zero-width matches*](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#zero_width), ou *assertions*).

Ou seja, o trecho `(?<=\D)` só verifica se antes do sinal (`[+-]`) existe um caractere que corresponde a `\D`, mas esse caractere não fará parte do *match*. Portanto, a regex não vai mais pegar o caractere que tem antes do sinal.

[Veja funcionando no regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rGgE94/2/).

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado, estudarei mais esse Lookbehind pois não entendi muito bem. Mas agradeço.